# How to pass custom options to fab command

Tags: python, fabric

I want to reuse the fabfile for multiple projects.

**config.ini**

```
[project1]
git_repo = git@github/project1
project_path = '/path/project1'
[project2]
git_repo = git@github/project22
project_path = '/path/project2'
```

**fabfile.py**

```
from fabric import task
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("conf.ini")

@task
def getcode(connection, project, git_repo):
    args = config['project]
    connection.run("git clone {}".format(git_repo))

@task
def pushcode(connection, project, git_repo):
    args = config['project]
    connection.run("git push {}".format(git_repo))
```

How can i avoid using `args = config['project]` in every method. Can I pass custom args with fab command `fab -H web1 --project=project1 pushcode` . Need help.

Comment: I wonder if my answer has helped you solving your problem/question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can pass arguments to fab tasks which call under the roof task from `invoke.task`. 
I will give an example how you can do it:
**fabfile.py**

```
from fabric import task

@task
def sampleTask(connection, name, laste_name, age):
    print("The firstname is ", name)
    print("The lastname is ", laste_name)
    print("The age is ", age)
```

and then you call it from the command line like this:
**Command-line**

```
fab sampleTask -n peshmerge -l Mo -a 28
```

The output should be like this:

```
[vagrant@localhost fabric]$ fab sampleTask -n peshmerge -l Mo -a 28
The firstname is Peshmerge
The lastname is Mo
The age is 28
```

Note: Giving your task a name which contains an underscore ( _ ) will result in an error

```
No idea what 'sample_task' is!
```

The same goes with naming the task arguments.

Comment: Thanks!! It's very difficult to find a good document for fabric. This answer saved a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Indeed, the `fab` CLI tool has the same options as Invoke's `inv` CLI tool.

And having a look at [that part of Invoke's docs](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/concepts/invoking-tasks.html), you can see that it is the same syntax that you proposed :)